# detach a process, then continue a command

Tags: bash, shell, process

When I try something like

```bsh
$command &; command2
```

, bash returns me

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This one you mean https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/67015/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `&` and `;` are command terminators. You use one or the other, but not both.

```bsh
some_command1 & some_command2

some_commandA ; some_commandB
```

is the same as

```bsh
some_command1 &
some_command2

some_commandA ;
some_commandB
```

... but the `;` is not needed when it's at the end of the line, so the second set of commands is the same as

```bsh
some_commandA
some_commandB
```

Comment: Okay I understand better, I never knew that `&` is not only to detach but to end the "line" too, thanks!